# Carabao and telescope story

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I am searching for a literature piece (I can not recall if it is a short story or poem) I have read in my fourth grade English book (around ten years ago) about a carabao and their telescope.

I can remember the author playing with the words *carabao* and *telescope* by providing portmanteaus *caracope* and *telebao* that are used throughout the piece. There is even a sketch of a naked carabao, with their back against the reader, looking through a telescope in a balcony from what looks like a tower during the night in the page.

It is one of my favorite pieces as a child because of the play on words and sadly I have no means of finding it.

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm not sure if "carabao" is being used with a different meaning. Sounds interesting if the story is about a naked [water buffalo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carabao)....

Comment: I don't think that the "carabao" is being used with a different meaning. Yes, I am referring to _Bubalus bubalis_.

Comment: Aren't water buffalos naked all the time? Why would one be naked with their back to a window?

Comment: Perhaps they're anthropomorphized and usually wear clothes in the story